# Store data from a triple for loop

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, for-loop, storing-data

I have this code that I wrote in MATLAB to store matrices. I was using cells array, but in Python I don't know how to do this.

Would someone know how can I do this?

The MATLAB code is:

```matlab
S =[0.5 0.7 0.9 1.1]; % distância entre tx e rx[m]
d = 0.2*ones(1,10); 
h = [ 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]

n_cam = length(d); % numero de camadas
n_alt = length(h); % numero de alturas
n_S = length(S); % numero de receptores
z = zeros(n_cam,n_alt); % profundidade
Rv_h = zeros(n_S,n_alt);
Rv_v = zeros(n_S,n_alt);
Rv = zeros(n_cam,n_alt);
Rh = zeros(n_cam,n_alt);
S_Rv = cell(1,n_S);
S_Rh = cell(1,n_S);
sigma = 0.3*ones(1,n_cam);
sigmaah = zeros(n_S,n_alt);


for i = 1:n_S
    for  j = 1:n_alt
        for k = 1:n_cam
            z(k,j)= (sum(d(1:k))+h(j))/S(i);
            Rv(k,j) = 1/((4*z(k,j)^2+1)^0.5);
            Rh(k,j) = ((4*z(k,j)^2+1)^0.5)-2*z(k,j);
        end 
        Rv_h(i,j) = 1/((4*(h(j)/S(i))^2+1)^0.5);
        Rh_h(i,j)=((4*(h(j)/S(i))^2+1)^0.5)-2*(h(j)/S(i));
    end
    S_Rv(:,i) = {Rv}; % z para cada camada em cada altura, para cada S
    S_Rh(:,i) = {Rh};
end

for i = 1:n_S
    for  j = 1:n_alt
        Rv = cell2mat(S_Rv(1,i));
        Rh = cell2mat(S_Rh(1,i));
        sigma_ah = sigma(1)*(Rh_h(i,j)-Rh(1,j));
        sigma_av = sigma(1)*(Rv_h(i,j)-Rv(1,j));
        for k = 2:(n_cam-1)
           sigma_ah_ant = sigma_ah;
           sigma_av_ant = sigma_av;
           sigma_ah = sigma_ah_ant + sigma(k)*(Rh(k-1,j)-Rh(k,j));
           sigma_av = sigma_av_ant + sigma(k)*(Rv(k-1,j)-Rv(k,j));
        end
        sigmaah (i,j)  = sigma_ah + sigma(end)*Rh(n_cam-1,j)
        sigmaav (i,j)  = sigma_av + sigma(end)*Rv(n_cam-1,j)
    end
end
```

I was thinking that in Python I could do something like:

```
n_S = 4
n_alt = 9
n_cam = 6
Rv =[]
for i in range(1,n_S):
    for j in range(1,n_alt):
        for k in range(1,n_cam):
            z[k][j]= (sum(d[0:k])+h[j])/S[i]
            Rv[i][j][k] = 1/((4*z[k,j]**2+1)**0.5)
```

But it is not working, the error message I get is

> list index out of range.

Comment: There are several variables (or functions, not sure which) that you don't appear to define (at least in this code snippet): `z` and `d` being among them. Also, what do you mean by "it's not working?" Are there specific error messages you see?

Comment: missing `z` `d` `h` `S` definitions. Also as @JonahBishop said, what is 'not working'?

Comment: I didn't put all code...d = 0.2*ones(1,10),  h = [ 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]  z is calculate from d and h

Comment: Well put all the code so we can help you.

Comment: @antfuentes87 done! =)

Comment: @JonahBishop the error I get in python is "list index out of range"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest taking use of the [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) feature

The loops can then be replaced to clarify the code :

```
from numpy import array, ones
S =array([0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.1])
d = 0.2*ones((10)); 
h = array([ 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])

z = ((d.cumsum()[:, None] + h).ravel() / S[:, None]).reshape((S.size, d.size, h.size))
Rv = 1 / (4 * z ** 2 + 1)** .5
# ...etc
print(Rv[-1])
```

Which outputs:

```
    [[0.93979342 0.87789557 0.80873608 0.73994007 0.67572463]
 [0.80873608 0.73994007 0.67572463 0.61782155 0.56652882]
 [0.67572463 0.61782155 0.56652882 0.52145001 0.48191875]
 [0.56652882 0.52145001 0.48191875 0.4472136  0.41665471]
 [0.48191875 0.4472136  0.41665471 0.38963999 0.36565237]
 [0.41665471 0.38963999 0.36565237 0.34425465 0.32507977]
 [0.36565237 0.34425465 0.32507977 0.30782029 0.29221854]
 [0.32507977 0.30782029 0.29221854 0.27805808 0.26515648]
 [0.29221854 0.27805808 0.26515648 0.25335939 0.24253563]
 [0.26515648 0.25335939 0.24253563 0.23257321 0.22337616]]
```

Which overlaps with the computation in octave/matlab:

```
Rv =

   0.93979   0.87790   0.80874   0.73994   0.67572
   0.80874   0.73994   0.67572   0.61782   0.56653
   0.67572   0.61782   0.56653   0.52145   0.48192
   0.56653   0.52145   0.48192   0.44721   0.41665
   0.48192   0.44721   0.41665   0.38964   0.36565
   0.41665   0.38964   0.36565   0.34425   0.32508
   0.36565   0.34425   0.32508   0.30782   0.29222
   0.32508   0.30782   0.29222   0.27806   0.26516
   0.29222   0.27806   0.26516   0.25336   0.24254
   0.26516   0.25336   0.24254   0.23257   0.22338
```

This reduces the pyramid of doom and is probably faster than the for-loops due to numpy magic.
Edit: formatting
Edit2: gave check

Comment: I don't understand the code, works for storing the data, but the Rv result is not the same from matlab... The d.cumsum() goes just until the index it is supposed to?

Comment: I had the parenthesis wrong. Edited the code snippet above to match your line. Essentially what how it works is similar to bsxfun in matlab. I am repeatedly doing an operation over the other dimensions. 

.cumsum() performs the cumutilative sum similar to what you are doing. The only difference is that my results are appended along the third axis. Which you don't use since you are overwriting z matrix.

Comment: Also added confirmation with output of the last iteratons

Comment: thank you very much! works great! this is much ahead of my knowledge in python

Comment: No problem. Just be mindful that this is numpy magic and not necessarily python. Numpy arrays are very useful for numerical computations compared to normal lists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `z` and `Rv` to be 2D and 3D arrays of known size before you do this.

Note also that python (and numpy) arrays are zero-based, so just use `range` directly.

Not tested:

```
import numpy as np

d = 0.2*np.arange(10)   ### not sure if this is what you meant
h = np.array([ 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4])

n_S = 4
n_alt = 9
n_cam = 6
Rv = np.zeros((n_S, n_alt, n_cam))
z = np.zeros((n_cam, n_alt))
for i in range(n_S):
    for j in range(n_alt):
        for k in range(n_cam):
            z[k][j]= (sum(d[0:k])+h[j])/S[i]   ## not sure about 0:10
            Rv[i][j][k] = 1/((4*z[k,j]**2+1)**0.5)
```

However, as @GlobalTraveler points out, the most pythonic/numpyish way to do this is to take advantage of broadcasting and not use a loop at all:

```
Rv = 1/np.sqrt(4 * z**2 + 1)
```